# CSS only for mobile

Tags: css, iphone, mobile

i want the green and red box to be smallere at mobile (iPhone): http://shop.cykel-expressen.dk/booking/

I thought this was the code, but it is not working, but isn't working)):

```
@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) .dopsp-body { .dopsp-body height: 50xp }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `{` after the `(max-width: 480px)`

```
@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .dopsp-body { height: 50px }
}
```

Comment: This response answers the question as to why the CSS isn't working. @W. Viksø, you should probably also consider that this style _will not_ be applied to screens with a size of 320px, which is what it sounds like you want. In this case you should remove the `(min-width:321px)` part - height will be 50px from 0 to 480px instead of 321px to 480px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query for this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
//Reduce the size of green and red box here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method, try to this.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {.dopsp-body {height: 50px }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try first is for portrait second for landscape code is on http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ has plenty of good snippets

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```